# UWP: Video Player Synchronization

Tags: winapi, uwp, video-player

I need to implement video playback that can synchronize to audio.
My use case is an audio/music application that can synchronize audio playback to other devices on the local network.
The important thing to note is that I *cannot* synchronize audio to video (but the other way around) because it would mean a complete overhaul of the entire playback engine.
Now I want to add the capabability to play back video (just plain play back without any effects).
Both video and audio live in the same process (obviously on different threads though)

What I have done on iOS:

- Get synchronization info from the the audio thread conisting of: position in the time line to absolute wall clock time
- Tell AVFoundation's video player to synchronization to that info via https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1386591-setrate

This AVFoundation's setRate function is immensely handy for me and from a video playback perspective I am done on iOS.
Now I need to implement the same thing for the Universal Windows Platform.

I have tried to use the way described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer .
But it seems the built-in video player isn't built for this kind of use case, which is sort of expected. In essence the uwp's MediaPlayer is not accurate enough.

- It lacks the mentioned setRate function for synchronizing video clip time to absolute wall time.
- Trying to play back anything ( `mediaPlayer.Play()`) it will of course play back, but not will always have an unpredictable delay.
- Also (which is really strange): setting its position to (for example) 2 seconds, will actually not set it to exactly 50 frames in a 25 fps movie clip. It is always slightly off.

I have looked into libvlc (and especially libVLCSharp), but I didn't find what I am looking for there as well. Maybe I am missing something though.
What I essentially need is either of the following:

- A way similar to AVFoundation's setRate synchronization -OR-
- A way to start video play back *immediately* when invoked

Or of course a completely different way I haven't thought of.

**Edit:**

I don't ask for a solution specifically targeting uwp apps but Windows in general.

Comment: Do you want it explicitly on UWP (which is officially deprecated) or to Windows more generally? More on this https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/

Comment: If you are referring to libVLCSharp I would say: Windows more generally. As far as I know, I should be able to use any Windows API as long as it doesn't break sandboxing, right? Thanks for the link!

Comment: LibVLCSharp is probably too high lever for what you're trying to achieve. I don't think you can "sync" stuff, except by passing the delay as the argument. Maybe you'd have better chances with libav* libraries and FFmpeg.AutoGen instead.

Comment: OK, in principle I am not against low level stuff.

Comment: If you don't need to target the UWP you can probably use the [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) for this.

Comment: My current approach is using ffmpeg for decoding and setting this as a MideaStreamSource to a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement. (using this https://github.com/microsoft/FFmpegInterop). The timing part still seems all over the place though.

Comment: @IInspectable note that Media Foundation supports UWP

Comment: @AhmedWalid I believe that's only true for a subset of Media Foundation (e.g. [`MFCreateMediaType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatemediatype)). The majority of APIs is marked as *"desktop apps only"* (like [`MFCreateMediaSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemediasession)).

Comment: @IInspectable while MFCreateMediaSession is desktop-only, many of the things marked as desktop-only on the docs are wrong, an alternative for this one is MFCreatePMPMediaSession, I'm also pretty sure everything the OP would need is allowed

Comment: BTW desktop-only functions work normally if you force them to, like you can load lib using LoadLibrary then get the address of the function and call it and it will just work (LoadLibrary is officially allowed under UWP now (as of 1809 iirc))

Comment: @AhmedWalid The documentation is indeed frequently wrong, so I always look into the header files to know, which APIs are actually allowed under the UWP application model. Interestingly, `LoadLibrary` indeed is. Though there's also a `CURRENT_IMPORT_REDIRECTION_VERSION` preprocessor symbol defined, and I don't know how that factors into the `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` scheme. Have you been successful using this for arbitrary API calls from a UWP application in the past?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, pretty much all the functions I tried using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress under UWP worked

Comment: BTW you can also get the an address of already loaded libraries from the PEB if you don't want to use LoadLibrary to do so, RegistryRT (a library) does that for example

Comment: Also I think it's worth mentioning that headers are sometimes wrong too, the most accurate source I have seen is WACK's XML files, ex: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_sdk10_19041/master/App%20Certification%20Kit/SupportedAPIs-x64.xml